# I want to use capital Greek letters and less < and greater than in same equation

Tags: math-mode, math-fonts

I want to use the less than symbol < and greater than > in and equation and capital letters from  Greek alphabet in particular \Phi. Now, I need the \usepackage{breqn} to put the less than greater than in an equation, but this package prevents capital Greek letters by giving a black square. I know I can take the <, > out of equations, but I've wrote pages of equations with them in. Removal of the  \usepackage{breqn} enables use of capital Greek letters, but removes the <,> from inside equations
MWE

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
% !TeX spellcheck = en_GB
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
%\documentclass[14pt,hidelinks]{article}
\usepackage{fouriernc}


\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{parskip}% this stops indent of first line in paragraph
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathpazo} %and mathptmx package for extra large fonts
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[%
colorlinks=true,%
urlcolor=blue%
]{hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{breqn}   % this is needed for less than greater than in formulas but prevents capital greek letters 
\usepackage{mathtools}% need for floor
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\ceil{\lceil}{\rceil} %needed for ceiling
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\floor{\lfloor}{\rfloor} % need for floor

\usepackage{bigints} % larger integral signs

\usepackage{bm} 





\begin{document}
\begin{eqnarray*} P(-1.5\leq Z\leq 0.5) &=& \Phi(0.5) - \Phi(-1.5)\\ &=& \Phi(0.5) - (1 - \Phi(1.5)) \\ &=& 0.6915 - (1-0.9332) = 0.6247,\end{eqnarray*}

The probability that  $X$ is less than 4 is  $ P(X < 4) $ Now, because \textbf{X}  only takes integer values
\begin{equation} P(X \textless 4) = P(X \le 3) = F(3) = 0.85. \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: ". Now, I need the \usepackage{breqn} to put the less than greater than in an equation, " ???? breqn implements a highly experimental line breaking feature, it does not change the fonts or characters available

Comment: you are loading multiple incompatble font choices, what font do you want for math fouriernc, amssymb, mathpazo

Comment: don't use \textless in math, use <

Comment: Off-topic but load `hyperref` last too, except for certain packages like `glossaries`, `cleveref` etc `hyperref` should always be loaded last. The exceptions are contained in the documentation on CTAN that you have as a comment after `\usepackage{hyperref}`

Comment: David, thanks for your comments. Have you tried putting in < and > in an equation. These characters will not not show. You have to use \usepackage{breqn} I am using Texstudio. Also, the font is very pleasing on the eye when the package \usepackage{fouriernc} is used when I build and view

Comment: Removed packages amssymb, and mathpazo font looks ok, but capital Greek letters are now tiny u's.

Comment: "Have you tried putting in < and > in an equation."  er yes  I have been doing that for over 30 years:-)

Comment: you can use fouriernc if that is the font you want but you can not specify multiple incompatble font encodings to be used at the same time. Breqn only accidentally is affecting the fonts here as the math setup was already broken by the other packages.

Comment: David, thanks for your help removed packages ammssymb, mathpazo, and breqn, and font looks nice. I can also put < > into equations and capital Greek Letters.

Comment: since you have a tested fix, could you post a self answer, thanks.

Comment: @Rmano The first magic comment says xelatex, so T1 isn't advisable `;-)`

Comment: The default text font encoding (which is only 7 bits) doesn’t have `<` or `>`, but any math font font package that’s been updated in the last thirty years should. Try `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use packages for multiple fonts. Packages `amssymb`, `mathpazo`, and `breqn` removed. Less than `<` and greater `>` can now be put into maths equations along with capital Greek letters.